# Opening videos in browser with XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: web-part, document-library, content-query-web-part, silverlight, xslt-list-view-web-part

I created a Document Center site which has its own Content Query Web Parts. When I upload a video file to this document center, the Content Query Web Parts are playing the videos in browser with modal SilverLight popup player.

When I add a webpart of my normal document library to this document center its added as a default XsltListViewWebPart which does not use the SilverLight player for videos.

Is it possible to customize the XsltListViewWebPart somehow, so that it will open the videos with the same SilverLight player?

Answer (score 1):

XLVWPs use the XSL for list views to render content. CQWPs use their own XSL. Theoretically, you could create a new list view and have that view use the same XSL that the CQWP uses (\Style Library\XSL Style Sheets\ItemStyle.xsl).